# Show info stored in table td on hover or click

Tags: jquery

What would be the easiest way to show info stored in each table cell data-id on hover or click (mobile device). I'm not sure how it works on mobile devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/p134uhev/

```
$('.shippingrates td').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-id');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to implement `hover` dialogs would be to use the bootstrap `popover` library.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on bottom</button>
```

Comment: Had to include a bunch of new javascript but that's what I went with. Thanks

Comment: @Ron No problem. Considering you had already implemented jQuery, I figured using a jQuery library would've suited best for you in stead of creating an entirely new widget.